# Grid Nic Add stationary row

Tags: grid

I am using GridNic for printing reports. I want to add a row at the bottom containing total of a column. I searched across the web but couldn't find a solution.

I tried to add an extra array index in dataset containing total of a column, but when I sort the table it no longer remains at the bottom.

Also, I'll really appreciate if somebody can share GridNic documentation with me. The documentation on GridNic site is not really helpful.

thanks in advance!!

Comment: ANYBODY???? I hardly remember getting answer to my question EVER!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brute force: cannot find elegant solution
Works for me on SlickGrid:
In sort handle before call sort method clone your total row, then call sort method, then place copy back 
Hope will help